# Redirecionamento automático de paginas

Tags: php

Eu tenho 3 paineis,exemplo:

painel1.php

painel2.php

painel3.php

Eles vão ficar exibindo em um monitor, o que gostaria:

Que fosse aberto um só na tela, e que a cada 10 segundos o navegador mudasse automaticamente para o outro.

Como poderia fazer esse processo ?

Comment: É mais recomendável fazer em javascript.Pois PHP não fica ouvindo o tempo, não tem esse poder, a linguagem PHP é para escrever páginas. Já o javascript sim é para interagir.

Comment: A função pode ser tranquilamente escrita em PHP combinando um loop com a função sleep()

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pode fazer isso com meta tag de HTML, insira-as no `<head>`:

Com intervalo de tempo de 10 secs em cada, no seu caso:

Do painel1.php para o painel2.php, insira a seguinte meta tag no painel1.php:

```
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="10;URL=painel2.php">
```

Do painel2.php para o painel3.php, insira a seguinte meta tag no painel2.php:

```
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="10;URL=painel3.php">
```

Do painel3.php de volta para o painel1.php, insira a seguinte meta tag no painel3.php:

```
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="10;URL=painel1.php">
```

Isto vai estar em loop

Comment: Perfeito,obrigado.

Comment: De nada @OtácioBarbosa, bom ter ajudado

Answer (score 1):

Já que vai ficar exposto, melhor usar um Javascript para colocar um efeito de transição, redirect não são esteticamente legais.

HTML

```
<div class="wrap"></div>
```

CSS

```
* {padding:0;margin:0;}
.wrap {width:100%;height:100%;display:none;}
```

JS

```
$(document).ready(function(){ 

    //As páginas a serem carregadas devem estar na mesma pasta da sua aplicação
    url1 = 'money.php';
    url2 = "moneyMoney.php";
    url3 = "moneyMoneyMoney.php";
    atual = 2;

    $('.wrap').fadeIn(2000).load(url1);
    setInterval(trocar,15000);    

    function trocar(){
        $('.wrap').fadeOut(2000,function(){ 
            switch(atual){
                 case 1: 
                     $('.wrap').load(url1);
                     atual++; 
                 break;
                 case 2:
                     $('.wrap').load(url2);
                     atual++; 
                 break;
                 case 3: 
                     $('.wrap').load(url3);
                     atual = 1; 
                 break;
            }
            $('.wrap').fadeIn(2000); 
        });   
    }

});
```

Comment: Gostei muito,Obrigado. Ultilizei a do @miguel mais também testei a sua,Obrigado pela contribuição.